# How to change a Decimal? to 3 decimal points U-SQL

Tags: u-sql, decimal-point

Thanks in advance for any help!

I have a column stored as a decimal? and I am trying to load it into another table and change it to 3 decimal points.

I have tried:

```
Math.Round(mycolumn, 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) AS my_column
```

This gives the error:

> cannot convert from 'decimal?' to 'double'.

Many thanks,

BigD

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to cast it to the proper type:

```
(decimal?)( Math.Round((decimal)mycolumn, 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero))  AS mycolumn,
```